# What word could describe whether something is indoors or outdoors?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm currently building a website for RC car racing and need a word that could describe whether a race track is indoors or outdoors.

On the website itself, I have a dropdown menu that contains the options 'indoor' and 'outdoor' and I need a heading to describe the options. I also need to name the database field that holds this information.

I have thought about Track Type, Track Location and many others but I'm wondering if there is a word out there that better describes these two options.

Comment: Would 'location' work?

Comment: venue, circuit, place...

Comment: I would propose "doorsiness".  Of course that would get me some very strange looks.

Comment: Maybe "usage" ?

Comment: I like it @HotLicks.  My current doorsiness is in, but I wish it were out.

Comment: If it's only a heading & the options will be clear from the dropdown, if you need to be precise you could just put "in/out-doors" (with or without the hyphen).

Comment: @TrevorD - Yep, "in outdoors" would be perfect!

Comment: For future references, is there a reason why this question was downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about "environment"? (That could also allow finer granularity later for types of outdoor: grass vs. gravel or whatever).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe "track setting" would be a good option.

Comment: Yes, that could work well. I will hang on for a bit longer to see what other suggestions there are. Thank you!